# sqlite3 create table problems

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I have an app I'm developing that will store soccer match statistics but I'm having trouble with my sqlite database. My save method is this :

```
-(void) saveData{
    NSString *databasePath;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath =[databasePath UTF8String];


    char *errMsg;


    NSString *games;
    games= @"games";
    NSString *entree =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"create table if not exists %@(id integer, home text, away text)", games];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_gameFile)==SQLITE_OK){
        if(sqlite3_exec(_gameFile, [entree UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errMsg) !=SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"executing %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_gameFile));
        } else {
            NSLog(@"table created (%@)", entree);
        }
}
    sqlite3_close(_gameFile);
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_gameFile)==SQLITE_OK){

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO games (id, home, away) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")", dataPoints[0], dataPoints[1], dataPoints[2]];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_gameFile, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        int rc =sqlite3_step(statement);
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"success");
            NSLog(@"tried to enter %@" , insertSQL);
        } else if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_MISUSE){
            NSLog(@"%@", insertSQL);
            NSLog(@"Error %s while preparing statement", sqlite3_errmsg(_gameFile));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_gameFile);
    }
}
```

This produces the following entries in the log:

```
2014-12-10 15:25:32.752 Footy Predictor[1718:513765] table created (create table if not exists games(id integer, home text, away text))
2014-12-10 15:25:32.759 Footy Predictor[1718:513765] INSERT INTO games (id, home, away) VALUES ("1446","Den Haag","Excelsior")
2014-12-10 15:25:32.760 Footy Predictor[1718:513765] Error no such table: games while preparing statement
```

I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong as the log says table created, and then says no such table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Almost certainly because there is not a valid (& writeable) DB path.  Is the above code accurate in that you're not setting the path at all, or have you omitted the code (that likely attempts to allocate the DB in the wrong place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an explicit answer for you because there are quite a few things that can go wrong with sqlite.

The main thing I can see is that you are not initialising `databasePath`. This needs to be a path to the .db file e.g. ~/Desktop/myDatabase.db.

1) I assume that you only want to process the `statement` once and you are actually inserting it 3 times. you need to check the value of `rc` i.e. only call `sqlite3_step` once and then put `rc` into the `if` statements :

```
int rc =sqlite3_step(statement);
        if(rc == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"success");
            NSLog(@"tried to enter %@" , insertSQL);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", insertSQL);
            NSLog(@"Error %s while preparing statement", sqlite3_errmsg(_gameFile));
        }
```

2) Check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` for success.

3) You neeeeed to normalise your statements ([documentation for sqlite3_bind](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)), otherwise you will run into problems when your users enter wildcard characters e.g. "?" or statements like "DROP"

4) Have you considered using Core Data. It is sooo much easier (although not ideal for everyone's needs I know).

Comment: Thanks very much. It was the databasePath problem that was stopping it from working. I still have much to learn and I have taken all of your advice on board. And I'm off to look at Core Data.

Comment: No problem. Core Data can look daunting at first but give it a couple of days concerted effort and it becomes very easy to use.